# Cost of DPUs for parallel Running Job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am running 10 concurrent run of same glue job.The job is taking Lot of DPUs.Does concurrent run of same glue job take more DPUs than running multiple different glue jobs in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Generally it should not matter if you run your jobs in parallel or sequentially. Every job will consume some DPUs and is directly based on the time it takes. So 1 job for 10 mins and 10 jobs for 1 min should result in same cost.

You can refer to pricing examples in the documentation page.
https://aws.amazon.com/glue/pricing/

Or can share more data (screenshot maybe) of how you're calculating the pricing.